# Implementing ToString for a struct in Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an ASP.NET Core project and I am trying to convert a Persian date and store it.

```
public struct PersianDateTime
{
    private DateTime _dateTime;

    public PersianDateTime(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        _dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public DateTime GeoDateTime => _dateTime;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
        int month = pc.GetMonth(_dateTime);
        int dayOfMonth = pc.GetDayOfMonth(_dateTime);
        return string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2} {3}:{4}:{5}",
            pc.GetYear(_dateTime),
            month < 10 ? "0" + month.ToString() : month.ToString(),
            dayOfMonth < 10 ? "0" + dayOfMonth.ToString() : dayOfMonth.ToString(),
            _dateTime.Hour < 10 ? "0" + _dateTime.Hour : _dateTime.Hour,
            _dateTime.Minute < 10 ? "0" + _dateTime.Minute : _dateTime.Minute,
            _dateTime.Second < 10 ? "0" + _dateTime.Second : _dateTime.Second);
    }

    public PersianDateTime(int year, int month, int day)
    {
        PersianCalendar p = new PersianCalendar();

        _dateTime = p.ToDateTime(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    //...
}

public class Order
{
    //...
    public PersianDateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}

public class OrderConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Order> b)
    {
        //...

        b.Property(x => x.CreatedDate)
            .HasConversion(a => a.GeoDateTime, a => new PersianDateTime(a));
    }
}
```

And the date is properly saved and retrieved.

But when I have a search like this

```
context.Order.Where(x => x.CreatedDate.ToString().Contains("1402/01")).Tolist();
```

I get an error:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(o => o.CreatedDate.ToString().Contains("1402/01"))' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'object.ToString' failed.

How can I create a translation for `.ToString()` in EF Core?

Comment: Don't use `ToString()`. That's only valid in .Net. Instead search for a range directly - using `>=` and `<`. Then your value converter will translete to somthing you DB can understand and compare.

Comment: Instead of relying on ToString in the LINQ query, break down the components and use them in the query.
`context.Order
    .Where(x => x.CreatedDate.GeoDateTime.Year == 1402 && x.CreatedDate.GeoDateTime.Month == 1)
    .ToList();` This way, you're accessing the individual components directly, and EF Core should be able to translate this into a SQL query